# UK Short Term Study Visa

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, student-visa, uk-visa

While applying for UK short term study visa for a period of three months, I came across this question: "Total Monthly Income from savings, properties or other income, for example from stocks and shares".

In my bank account, I receive a monthly salary S from my employer. In addition to this I have an X sum of money in my bank account which I received from various sources including family members at various times. This X sum of money is there for more than previous six months and is available for me to spend on my studies. However, it is not a MONTHLY income. How do I represent this money as answer to the visa form question stated above? Do I show the total X amount of money as monthly income which it is not? Or do I divide the X by, say, 3 (three month visa) and write the amount from X/3 as answer to MONTHLY income from other sources?

I am confused and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your monthly income is that which is deposited into your account from a regular source, in this case by your employer. That portion of your bank statement would be supported by accompanying pay slips. However, the question you've quoted isn't precisely that. Usually, there are two separate questions:

1. What is your total monthly income from all sources of employment or occupation, after tax?
2. Do you have savings, properties or other income, for example from stocks and shares?

The first is where you indicate your salary or independent income (e.g., from consulting or your professional services). The second is where you'd show other monies regularly deposited, either transferred in from your savings or not related to employment income (e.g., from rental properties). It would be misleading and confusing to multiply the total and divide (your X/3).

Depending on the various sources you're describing, including family, you may need to explain where those funds come from, and that you 'own' them. Take care that they haven't been placed in your account temporarily, or [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking) as it's referred to on the sister site, Travel Stack Exchange.

Comment: This implies that I should enter '0' against  'Total Monthly Income from savings, properties or other income, for example from stocks and shares', as it is not strictly monthly income at all. Moreover, this is not funds parking but money saved for the sole purpose to spend on this trip for which I am applying for visa.

Comment: Part of my expenses are being sponsored by my employer. In addition, I also have a UK bank account in my name with address of my friend in the UK and it also has the amount of money I will need for this visit. I opened this account in one of my previous trips to keep some money for use in my later visits. Can I use the print outs of monthly statements from this account to support my visa application?

Comment: @KamranAli Yes, to the first one; 0 if you have none; and, yes, explain your employers's additional support, beyond your salary. If you include the UK account statements, you should include the explanation.